# How to access list of dictionary data with same fields in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
{
    "raw_output": {
        "data": {     
            "sleeps": "[\"{'summaryId': 'x209bf59-59b7574c-594c', 'durationInSeconds': 22860, 'startTimeInSeconds': 1505187660, 'startTimeOffsetInSeconds': -14400, 'deepSleepDurationInSeconds': 7680, 'lightSleepDurationInSeconds': 14100, 'awakeDurationInSeconds': 1080, 'validation': 'AUTO_TENTATIVE'}\", \"{'summaryId': 'x209bf59-59b7574c-6180', 'durationInSeconds': 24960, 'startTimeInSeconds': 1505187660, 'startTimeOffsetInSeconds': -14400, 'deepSleepDurationInSeconds': 7680, 'lightSleepDurationInSeconds': 16140, 'awakeDurationInSeconds': 1140, 'validation': '`AUTO_MANUAL`'}\"]",
        },
```

for example: I would like to access the value of validation of the first dict.

Comment: I would assuming that what you have provided here here comes from a print statement but if that were the case your string sleeps would be wrapped in single quotes not double...

Comment: Where is this data coming from, the embedded structures in strings seems very awkward to deal with, and it's not something simple like embedded `json`.

Answer (score 0):

The data embedded in strings needs to be parsed out, `ast.literal_eval()` can help with that, e.g.:

```
In []:
import ast
for d in ast.literal_eval(data['raw_output']['data']['sleeps']):
    i = ast.literal_eval(d)
    print(i['validation'])

Out[]:
AUTO_TENTATIVE
`AUTO_MANUAL`
```

Comment: Why do you use `ast.literal_eval` instead of just `eval`?

Comment: @kpie `eval()` is unsafe, as it will execute any arbitrary python code. `ast.literal_eval` will only parse literals.

Comment: its priniting two values in need only 1 value the first one and when am using this way (d["raw_output"]["sleeps"][0]['validation']) it is giving a error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: can u please help me to get a single value

Comment: if am following this method i am getting all the values can i filter unique values @AChampion

Answer (score 0):

Your value for sleeps appears to be a string. You need it to be a list.  You would may want to replace the string with a list of dictionaries following in order to make it readily index-able. (assuming the dictionary you printed out and posted was stored in a variable called d)

```
d["raw_output"]["sleeps"] = [eval(k) for k in eval(d["raw_output"]["sleeps"])]
```

With this done you can now print the value of validation from the first entry as follows.

```
print(d["raw_output"]["sleeps"][0]['validation'])
```

> As @AChampion pointed out (Epic user name btw) you probably want to
>   use ast.literal_eval instead of eval.

**I hope this helps!**

Answer (score -1):

dict["raw_output"]["data"]["sleeps"][0]["validation"] in this way you can access the value of validation.

Comment: dict should never be a variable name + that won't work as the value at location sleeps is a string not a dictionary. Further it is a string that represents a list, not a string representing a dictionary, so you are missing the indices ["sleeps"] and [0] between ["data"] and ["validation"].

Comment: Yes dict is used jus for some demonstration. Also i have edited it now. Haven't even noticed the [ and sleeps at first sight.

Comment: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`